# Read data from text files having same name structure and append all data into a new file

Tags: python, c, matlab, loops, append

I have some data files, say `data1.txt`, `data 2.txt`,... and so on. I want to read all these data files using a single loop structure and append the data values into a single file, say data-all.txt.

I am fine with any of the following programming languages: `c`, `python`, `matlab`

Comment: Do you have any prototype of your code? Give more details of your files. What is the structure of these files? Are they tab or comma-delimited? If this is the case, I suggest that you read about the csv module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: @Felipe All the data files are in `.txt` format. There are M rows and 3 columns with only numerical values and no text (not even header). The numerical values are tab-delimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pathlib` module is great for globbing matching files, and for easy read/write:

```
from pathlib import Path

def all_files(dir, mask):
    for path in Path(dir).glob(mask):
        yield from path.open()

Path('data_all.txt').write_text(''.join(all_files('.', 'data*.txt')))
```

Comment: Files whose name match a glob wildcard string.

Comment: Gosh, what a great module! Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: How about this sexy '/' operator overload? `dir_path = Path('/tmp/some/dir'); file_in_dir = dir_path / 'data1.txt'`  And there is also `rglob` for recursive glob.

Comment: I am getting following error while running this code: `SyntaxError: Invalid syntax` for the line 5, that is `yield from path.open()`

Comment: `yield from` is fairly new, I think Python 3.5. Replace it with `for line in path.open(): yield line`

Comment: Or, since you are just concatenting all the lines anyway, change that line to `yield path.read_text()`. My original idea with `all_files` was to make it a line-by-line iterator that would chain through all the matching files like they were one big file. But since you are just appending them all anyway, just yield the whole content of the file, as returned by `path.read_text()`

Comment: The problem is that 'data_all.txt' matches the same 'data*.txt' wildcard that matches 'data1.txt', 'data2.txt', etc. Try writing `data_all.txt` to a directory that is different from where all the others are stored.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I just renamed `data_all.txt` to `all-data.txt` so that it won't match the name structure.

Answer (score 0):

In python First of all you have to create the list of all file paths you can use the glob library in python.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
path_list = glob.glob('Path/To/Your/DataFolder/pattern(data*)')
```

then you can read that data using list comprehension.it will give you the list of data frames depending upon the data files in your folder

```
list_data = [pd.read_csv(x,sep='\t') for x in path_list]
```

It will combine the data in single data frame and you can write it as a single dataframe.

```
data_all = pd.concat(list_data,ignore_index=True)
```

now you can write the dataframe in a single file.

```
data_all.to_csv('Path',sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python **zip** and the **csv** module to achieve this. Within a single for loop:

For Example:

```
import csv
with open("data_all.csv", "w") as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    for d1, d2, d3 in zip(open("data1.txt", "r"), open("data2.txt", "r"), open("data3.txt", "r")):
        csv_writer.writerow([d1, d2, d3])
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through reading the content of each file, and writing them into an output file handle. The files structure in your description contains numbers, so we might need to call sorted to sort them before start reading. The "files_search_pattern" should point out to the input directory 'PATH/*.txt' and the same for the output file handle "data-all.txt"

```
import glob

files_search_pattern = "*.txt"

files = sorted(glob.glob(files_search_pattern))

with open("data-all.txt", "wb") as output:
    for f in files:
        with open(f, "rb") as inputFile:
            output.write(inputFile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows,  use
copy data*.txt data-all.txt

In Unix, use
cat data*.txt >> data-all.txt